# @font-face broken in child theme

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

In my site I'm using Bootstrap for the basic structure (`bootstrap.min.css`), and using my own stylesheet (`style.css`) for further enhancements or modification. I declared `@font-face` in my stylesheet like below:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto_condensedregular';
    src: url('fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.svg#roboto_condensedregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

It's working fine, but in my child theme Roboto font is not loading at all. I enqueued my styles in `functions.php` like below:

```
function project_child_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'project_child_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

I even tried redeclaring `@font-face` in my child theme with the parent theme's fonts path:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto_condensedregular';
    src: url('../parenttheme/fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../parenttheme/fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../parenttheme/fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../parenttheme/fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../parenttheme/fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.svg#roboto_condensedregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Either of the ways I checked the browser console and confirmed there is no 404 for the font files.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not there in your @font-face it's actually in the `functions.php` where you enqueued the stylesheets.

What I assume your parent theme is enqueuing stylesheets like below:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/themes/parenttheme/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='style-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/themes/parenttheme/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

But what's happening in your child theme:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='parent-style-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/themes/parenttheme/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='child-style-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/themes/childtheme/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/themes/parenttheme/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Because Child theme's code is getting priority.

So you would need something like below - a correct stylesheet-dependency-order ([as mentioned here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style#Parameters) with `$deps`):

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('bootstrap') );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'parent-style' ) );
```

Note, the `array('bootstrap')` declaration on parent style will load the parent style after bootstrap, and `array( 'parent-style' )` declaration on child style will load the child style after parent style.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/themes/parenttheme/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='parent-style-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/themes/parenttheme/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='child-style-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/themes/childtheme/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Follow the correct dependency accordingly if you have more other CSS files in your parent theme.

Comment: in my case, the parent minified css already includes bootstrap so all other parts of bootstrap css are working except the font. It won't load. Any other sugestions